# How do I find the mean of a set of numbers in a given time period in Ruby (especially in a csv file)?

Tags: ruby, csv

Here's a simple example of what I have in my CSV file:

```
"1","January 3, 2012"
"2","January 3, 2012"
"3","May 4, 2012"
"4","May 4, 2012"
"5","May 4, 2012"
"6","June 8, 2012"
"7","June 9, 2012"
"9","June 10, 2012"
"10","July 4, 2012"
"11","July 4, 2012"
"12","August 18, 2012"
```

I'd like my output to have the average value for each date (e.g., the average for January 3, 2012 is 1.5).

I have the 'crack' gem, so I can use the 'Time.parse' syntax, though I wonder if there's a way to do this without using any gems (or at least, nothing more than the 'crack' gem).

Comment: Have you got some code showing you've made an attempt to answer this?

Comment: Of course you could do it without gems, especially if the input is guaranteed regular. Split, create your own dates, throw the numbers into a hash, calculate the mean. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I would build an hash of arrays, where the keys to the hash are the date string, and the value would be the array of values.

You would then end up with a structure that looks like

```
{
  "January 3, 2012" => ["1", "2"],
  "May 4, 2012"     => ["3", "4", "5"],
  "June 8, 2012"    => ["6", "7"]
  ...
}
```

You would then iterate over each key-value pair in the hash

```
output = {}
input.each do |key, value|
  output[key] = value.map(&:to_i).inject(0.0, :+) / value.length
end
```

Comment: (I'd probably use `to_f` and the one-arg `inject`, but I'm just like that. This way might be more-visibly floaty.)

Comment: Yes, this code seems to work just fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you could accept the answer, then others will be helped as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, easy CSV parsing+storing sum and count of values in hash-like structure with dates as keys will do.

But this attitude of "post your code I'll pick the best" is not welcome here on SO.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I didn't intend it to mean that, but I can see how it would be interpreted that way.